# Does math lose the connection with the physical world after a point?

Tags: soft-question, education, advice

I am an engineering student, completed the course and worked for a while as a research associate, I always loved mathematics, but I couldn't pursue it as a full-time career.  Now I wish to do a master's and Ph.D. in mathematics, but I have been warned that it's not rosy as you think, because you may lose the connection with physical problems and you will deal with numbers only.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Many areas of advanced mathematics hardly use numbers at all

Comment: You can ask that question from the starting point. Is any of its assumptions (axioms) a property of the real world? And even further, what is the real world, is there a real world? Therefore, if from the beginning you have that issue, you can image that you have the same problem at any point.

Comment: @topeik I apologise for the unclear query. I don't have any issue or any images of how math will be, I enjoy doing it and I see it as a path to understand the nature. So, for me I see mathematics as a understanding the nature and after I got warned from few seniors and professors I thought to check among community because people who warned me have never pursued maths beyond school.

Comment: Ha! It should have been 'imagine' instead of 'image'.

Comment: @topeik thank you for your concern, but not helping with my query. And I am certain that I meant image.